# Writing a sugar function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I was trying to write a function that "sugars" lambda expressions, but it looks like I'm doing everything wrong. 
Idea is to have a function:

`makePretty :: UglyForm -> PrettyForm` that on input:

`(1+(2+(3+4)))` outputs `+ [1,2,3] (4)`

and

`(div (div (div 1 2) 3) 4)` results in `div (1) [2,3,4]`

This is a simplified version but the logic of transformation should be the same. I'm new to Haskell so my apologies if this is a trivial thing to ask, but I just can't help myself and need a gentle push towards a right direction.

Comment: What are the types UglyForm and PrettyForm?

Comment: the difference between Ugly and Pretty forms - Pretty allowed to have arrays, while Ugly forced to be recursive. For example UglyForm = Variable Int | Applicatoin UglyForm UglyForm, while PrettyForm = Vatiable Int | Applicatoin PrettyForm [PrettyForm]

Comment: I am not sure why this question is sub-zero voted. I find it to be an entertaining line of thought.

Comment: It's downvoted because the question itself shows no effort to actually write `makePretty`. Self-answered questions are fine, but this reads more like a blog post than an actual question.

Comment: I downvoted because the question lacks sufficient information to answer it. The OP's answer is fine (and positively voted), but it relies on a bunch of information that wasn't in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I shouldn't post here. Sorry for annoying this community.

Here is an answer in case somebody else would meet the same problem.

I'm using here the idea from CPS (Continuation Passing Style) and auxiliary function to not be involved in type conflicts.

```
sugar :: UglyForm -> PrettyForm
sugar (Variable s) = Variable' s
sugar (Operator x y) = peelExpr (Operator' [x] (sugar y))

peelExpr :: PrettyForm -> PrettyForm
peelExpr (Operator' x (Operator' y z)) = peelExpr (Operator' (x++y) z)
peelExpr (Operator' x y) = Operator' x y
```

It looks simple and even trivial, so my apologies. 
This is simplified version that should on input:

`Operator "x" (Operator "y" (Operator "z" (Variable "a")))`

give you an answer

`Operator' ["x","y","z"] (Variable' "a")`

Data type could look like:

```
UglyForm = Variable String | Operator String UglyForm 
PrettyForm = Vatiable' String | Operator' [String] PrettyForm
```

Comment: I support your posting here with my votes. But you may also try [the Haskell subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/). It is a different kind of mess, and may be more conducive to your _"informal"_ manner of conversation.